# How to draw an arc between two known points in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview

[image]

I want to draw an arc between point B to point D and it should touch to point E. ( I want to draw AND gate symbol )
I tried this way

```
QPainterPath path;    
path.arcTo(60,30,46,100,30*16,120*16); // ( x,y,width,height, startAngle,spanAngle)
```

But it is drawing full circle and not in proper place.

Currently it is looking like this

[image]

After getting suggestion I tried like this :

```
path.moveTo(106, 80);
path.arcTo(76.0, 30.0, 60.0, 100.0, 90.0, -180.0);
```

How to get rid of that vertical line ( inside AND gate ) ?
Why it is appearing ?

Comment: 120 * 16 is *several* circles worth of an arc. A circle is 360 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the parameters for [arcTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#arcMoveTo-1), especially the bounding rectangle.

Given your image, you should move path to `(106, 80)` (center of the bounding rectangle)

`path.moveTo(106, 80)`;

The [bounding rectangle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#arcTo) of the arc should look like this:

- x: 76
- y: 30
- width: 60
- height: 100

The arc itsel should have a `start angle` at `90°` and should span `180°` in negative direction.

This results in:

`path.arcTo(76.0, 30.0, 60.0, 100.0, 90.0, -180.0);`

**Update**

[arcTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#cubicTo)

```cpp
path.moveTo(106, 30);
path.cubicTo(QPointF(156.0, 30.0), QPointF(156.0, 130.0), QPointF(106.0, 130.0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your suggestion worked. But there is a vertical line appearing inside AND gate. I have posted its pic. Can you say, why it is appearing ? And how to get rid of it ?

Comment: Okay, the vertical line appears, because the `arcTo` draws from the `startpoint` (in our case `moveTo`) a line to the beginning of the arc, draws the arc, and if you would use `closeSubpath()` there would be 2 lines.

You could try `cubicTo`, I will update my answer

Comment: I tried to change path.moveTo(106,30) and it worked.

Comment: Okay, nice. I haven't thought about that :-)

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get value of X ?  Y ? width ? ( it should be 46 ) ?

Comment: The `bounding rectangle` is the key.

The `arc` is a circle inside a rectangle. This rectangle is defined by the `upper left` corner (x, y) and spans a given width and height. I gave you the start coordinate for this rectangle, so that the center will be right below the endpoint of your upper-line.

Comment: Can I say, `(x,y)` co-ordinates of `bounding rectangle` (i.e. `(76,30)` ) you have chosen are random ? Means can I start my rectangle from `(86,30)` and accordingly width will be reduced.

Comment: You gave the points `B(106, 30)`, `E(136, 80)`, `D(106, 130)`. I wanted my arc to start at 106 with x-expansion of 30 to go through `E` ->  `x=76=106-(136-106)`. You can start at `86`, but you have to keep in mind, that with my given solution, you are starting vertically with `90° above the center`.